# Regular Expression: if, else if to use in Java

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in which I want to compare the URL's.

Any URL Matches
`http://*.xyz.com`
Except or Excluding
`http://m.xyz.com` and `http://m.product.xyz.com`

So far I was trying to do it by using if else in RegExp but I couldn't be able to do it right...

```
(^http:\/\/)(((1)<!(m|m\.product))\.xyz\.co\.jp)?
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try that:

```
^http:\/\/(?!m\.xyz\.com|m\.product\.xyz\.com).*\.xyz\.com$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPM44M/2)

Comment: It worked perfectly. Now i know what was the mistakes i was doing. Thanks very much

Comment: @ShanArshad Could you accept the answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

`https?:\/\/(?!m\.|m\.product\.).*\.xyz\..*`

This regex accepts all `*.xyz.*` domains except `m.xyz.*` and `m.product.xyz.*`. Also takes care of `http` or `https`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HHxfsf/2)